# Users can't open PDF after SP2016 March 2017 CU

Tags: 2016, library, pdf, word-pdf

Just installed March 2017 CU for SharePoint 2016. Now users can't open PDFs. When clicked in a library, Adobe Acrobat opens with the error `There was an error opening this document. This file cannot be found.` Meanwhile, the browser directs the user to the Word Online which opens the PDF.

If I go directly to the PDF, i.e. http://example.com/sites/site/documents/file.pdf, it opens fine in IE, using whatever IE uses to view PDFs.

It appears the click event in the library is causing a ruckus...

**UPDATE**

I've since removed the OWA server entirely from the farm (in dev) and now Adobe opens the file alone as expected. Adding it back in since it's def a OWA server issue.

Also tried installing the latest CU for OWA/OOS, but that errors out saying the expected version doesn't exist...

Comment: did SharePoint config wizard complete without any error? also try to clear the browser cache then try again.

Comment: The config wizard ran no problem. I just tried on a new browser, same issue.

Comment: Have you solved the problem and how? Since we are experiencing the same issue after the SP2016 December 2019 CU update.

Answer (score 6):

Install the May 2017 PU and try that. There was a bug, though I thought it was exclusive to 2013 with opening files where the path contained a space.

Comment: What/where indicates this should fix the problem? Hesitant to install updates "hoping" for a fix

Comment: Windows Update installed http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/KB/3191880 over the weekend, I reran psconfig on each box. Still erroring